# Why are linear functions linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, arithmetic

I always thought linear functions need to satisfy
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).$$
I am a tad confused now, consider $f(x)=2x+3$. $f(1)=5$, $f(2)=7$, $f(1+2)=f(3)=9 \neq f(1)+f(2)$ which was what I thought linear functions should satisfy.

Could someone clarify?

Comment: You are right, linearity means $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Functions on ${\mathbb R}$ which really are linear are of the form $f(x)=kx$ for some $k\in {\mathbb R}$. THose of form $f(x)kx+n$ with a nonzero $n$ should be called *affine*.

Comment: here f is not a linear function.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on "linear function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) could have warned you that these are false friends.

Comment: This looks related to [Why Rotations (in CG) are not linear?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1133790)

Comment: @robjohn: that's a good answer to link here as an addendum: how to make affine functions actually linear (by increasing the dimension of the space). But the only real duplicate listed here insofar is the Wikipedia link (and that's not on-site).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: I wasn't saying it was a duplicate, just related.

Comment: Related to [What is the difference between linear and affine function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275310/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-and-affine-function).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're confusing between two different notions.

In calculus, a linear function is a polynomial function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$.

In linear algebra and functional analysis, a linear function is a linear map.
(one of the properties that it satisfies is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, known as *additivity*)

The difference between the two is that the latter needs to have $f(0)=0$. *Proof:* $$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)\iff f(0)=0.$$
I discuss this in more detail in my (not yet finished) [note](http://nebula.wsimg.com/4e75e65515644b0b6a6ca4acbfffa0cb?AccessKeyId=36E442778196AE8E8F3A&disposition=0&alloworigin=1).

Comment: actually, $f(x) = a x + b$ is called *affine* in the general, and *linear* iff $b=0$

Comment: @TemplateRex In most standard calculus textbook, a linear function is defined as a function whose graph is a line. That's why I emphasized the distinction between a linear function in the context of calculus, and in the context of linear algebra and functional analysis. Although I do agree that calling it affine would have been much better.

Comment: Not only in calculus. If you look up the definition of a [splitting field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field), it will probably talk about a polynomial splitting "into linear factors". The linear factors are not necessarily of the form $ax$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ = $2x$ + $3$ isn't a linear function (from and to the set of real numbers). You can easily see that $f(x+y)$ = $2x$ + $2y$ + $3$, and that $f(x)$ + $f(y)$ = $2x$ + $2y$ + $6$. Equality obviously fails.

A linear function (as a mapping from and to the set of real numbers) should be in the from $ax$, where $a$ is a constant real number.

Comment: You will find a large number of textbooks and [websites](https://www.google.com/search?q="linear+function") which would describe $f(x)=2x+3$ as a "linear function".  Others may not, but that merely means that the term is ambiguous.